# I cant add onclicklistener on a constaintlayout

Tags: kotlin, fragment

```
package com.example.nagaduserapp.Fragment

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.denzcoskun.imageslider.constants.ScaleTypes
import com.denzcoskun.imageslider.models.SlideModel
import com.example.nagaduserapp.PeopleActivity
import com.example.nagaduserapp.PinSetActivity
import com.example.nagaduserapp.R
import com.example.nagaduserapp.databinding.FragmentMainBinding

class MainFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = FragmentMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

    }
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentMainBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        val imageList = ArrayList<SlideModel>()
        imageList.add(SlideModel(R.drawable.banner1, ScaleTypes.FIT))
        imageList.add(SlideModel(R.drawable.banner2, ScaleTypes.FIT))
        imageList.add(SlideModel(R.drawable.banner3, ScaleTypes.FIT))

        val imageSlider = binding.imageSlider
        imageSlider.setImageList(imageList)
        imageSlider.setImageList(imageList, ScaleTypes.FIT)

        return binding.root
    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }
    companion object{
    }
}
```

When i am trying to code `binding.id.setonclicklistener{ intent = Intent(this, Activity::class.java) startactivity(intent)` its not working in `OncreateView` and `OncreatedView`

I was expecting that when click on the particular constaintlayout it will move in another activity. I was making an app which ralated to money transfer .